# Manually load data in Hazelcast distributed cache

Tags: hazelcast

I planned to use Hazelcast as a distributed cache in our application. We gotta load some static data of around 300 entries in the cache. We planned to use Embedded cache topology only. The cache is not backed up by any database. So the only source of data is that cache only. So I would like to know is is possible to load the data In the cache manually through some way rather than programmatically possibly be with Hazelcast Management centre?

And also please shower your views on Is the embedded topology will work for distributed caching when I deploy the application across different data centres?

Comment: Where is the data if it's not in a database ? Is it in a file ? [REST](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0-beta-1/clients/rest.html#latest-banner) might be another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Hazelcast 5.0, SQL can be used as a non-code option to load data from files and Kafka into Hazelcast maps. SQL command can be executed from the Management Center (SQL Browser) or from the `hz-cli` command line tool that comes with the ZIP distribution. You can use `hz-cli` to connect to Hazelcast cluster started as embedded.

To load data from file to map:

1. Register the file to Hazelcast using `CREATE MAPPING`, example: https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0-beta-1/sql/file-connector.html
2. Define the structure and the serialization options of the target map. Example: https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0-beta-1/sql/imap-connector.html
3. Run a query that reads from file and writes to the map. Example:

```
SINK INTO myMap
    SELECT id, ticker, price, amount FROM myFiles;
```

Example: https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0-beta-1/pipelines/learn-sql.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the artefacts, It helps. I do have one more question, with the embedded topology we can still make use of the distributed cache mechanism across different cluster or we should go with client-server topology only for distributed cache to be applied for across cluster scenario?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Client-server and embedded clusters offer the same set of features. The only difference is in the lifecycle: embedded cluster is started and lives in the JVMs of your applications. With client-server, the cluster has it's own set of JVMs, your applications hosts just the client. You can connect various applications to a single cluster to share data. The cluster can be both embedded or standalone (client-server mode).